# web2py: display full db field into html

Tags: python, web2py

In controllers/default.py

```
def test(): 
    return dict(test=db().select(db.tbl_profile.name))
```

I have {{=test}} in test.html but it returns to me:

```
 tbl_card.name
 Johnny Apples...
```

I just want the full complete name to be displayed in the html and not the name of the table.field or the incomplete name (cut off by ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db().select(db.tbl_profile.name)` is a `Rows` object -- even if it contains only one record. If you want to extract a single `Row` object, you have to do:

```
db().select(db.tbl_profile.name)[0]
```

or

```
db().select(db.tbl_profile.name).first()
```

The latter is preferable because it will simply return `None` if there are no records (whereas the first option will generate an exception in that case).

Once you have extracted the single `Row` object, you then still have to select the particular field you want to display, even if that is the only field in the `Row`. So, the code should be:

```
return dict(test=db().select(db.tbl_profile.name).first().name)
```

Comment: Thank you that was a very helpful explanation. How would I get all the names in the rows object?

Answer (score 1):

You can have all the rows displayed by just  db().select(db.tablename.fieldname). To handle the truncation issue, you can use SQLTABLE() and set truncate to None.

Comment: Please don't post questions as answers. Write a comment instead.

Comment: Thanks all, I've edited it to contain a answer. I was able to find my way around the previous question, so i decided to share.